# Fixing a spreadsheet reliant on importrange that is now super slow

Tags: google-sheets, optimization, google-sheets-formula

My team uses a spreadsheet that I have been asked to help optimise. I can't link the sheet because of confidential data but will try and describe the sheet and the issue I am running into.

There is a google form that puts information into a spreadsheet. Lets call that Sheet1. That holds about 4500 rows of information. Sheet2 importranges 5 columns from Sheet1 and then users type notes and information into the other columns in that sheet. Sheet1 and Sheet2 have a 1:1 correspondence but no formula to make sure that the records match each other.

There are about 3000 rows that have a "complete" status.

There are new records being entered into Sheet1 almost daily and Sheet2 needs to remain dynamic.

Because of the amount of people that use the sheet concurrently, the importrange formula and a couple vlookups in Sheet2, Sheet2 is grinding to a slow pace that I have been tasked with trying to optimise.

I've tried:
Considered removing the completed rows. That would mess up the 1:1 correspondence. Im not able to add the completed marker to Sheet1 to re-import only the "open" or not complete cases.

Copy/Paste values on the completed records. This essentially breaks the import range from working on the records below as the importrange needs to have free range basically.

Only copy/paste values the other formula on the completed records. This doesn't alleviate enough of the lag - its the importranges that are basically making everything slow.

What I would like to try next:
Is it possible to use an importrange or similar function to start the import range at row x?

There is not a common key between the records... the data that would make a great common key is in Sheet1 only.

Comment: I think you are having these issues because you are using the wrong tool.  You are using a spreadsheet as a database with concurrent users, edits, and linked tables.  that is *exactly* what a database program is designed to do seamlessly with much larger data.  Have you considered transitioning?  MS Access or something Google-ish (not sure what the options are)

Comment: @AirSquid you are not wrong there. 

Lets say then that I wanted to develop an application that would have one set of users entering information that is stored somewhere and another set of users that have access to see that information and then add notes, assign tags to that record - What languages would i use to develop such a tool?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to give a meaningful or specific evaluation or suggestion. If you don't want to share a link to your actual sheet, make a copy. Delete everything except for 10 rows of data and change the sensitive data for those 10 rows to *realistic* dummy data (e.g., change Kimberly Wilkerson to Minnie Mouse, etc.). Then share a link to that copy here. I build this kind of system for regular clients frequently, but I'd need to understand the full scope in order to point you in any specific direction.

Comment: In addition to my comment above, how many concurrent users are there? Are they working on the same/overlapping data (e.g., Person A may change Row 12 and then Person B may change the same fields on Row 12, etc.); or is each person assigned a specific and separate task or range to work on?

Comment: @ErikTyler Thank you for this. I might need to circle back on this later after I figure out what I can and cannot post. I really appreciate your comment and offer for help!